# Dynamically reposition a UI Button

Tags: ios, uibutton

I'm trying to change the position of my UIButton, which was positioned and sized in interface builder. I'm stumped.

I tried this code at the end of `viewDidAppear`:

```
[_smartphoneButton setFrame:CGRectMake( 20, 20, 100, 50 )];
```

Nothing changes. And yet i know `_smartphoneButton` is valid, because `_smartphoneButton.hidden = YES;` works, as well as changing the UIButton image.

And suggestions?

PS, none of these work either:

```
_smartphoneButton.frame = CGRectMake( 20, 20, 100, 50 );
```

or

```
_smartphoneButton.center = CGPointMake(10.0f, 10.0f);
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You most certainly don't "know it's valid" because of a `hidden` assignment.  Put a breakpoint in viewDidLoad and po that thing.

Comment: The `center` method started working. Didn't changed a thing either. Hm.

Comment: Have you try to Clean your build and build folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with CodaFi, put a break point to see the value of _smartphoneButton.
But even if `viewWillAppear` will work, I would suggest moving your code to `viewDidLoad` for the following reason.
`viewWillAppear` can get call several time in the live of a ViewController and you will be modifying the position of your button ofter for nothing.

Comment: How would that make it any better?  ViewDidAppear at least follows a presentation of the view (ergo, a redraw).  And besides, UIKit's rendering mechanism wouldn't just not redraw a button after it's frame has been set, they're smarter than that.

Comment: @CodaFi You are right,just tested it, the modification is occurring I always assumed that Apple was following their naming convention. Which "did" usually mean you get call after.